# How to connect Apache Spark to Cassandra cluster over SSL in Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, ssl, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

We are using Spark & Cassandra in an application which is deployed on bare metal/VM. To connect Spark to Cassandra, we are using following properties in order to enable SSL :

```
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.password
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.keyStore.type
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.protocol
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.path
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.password
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.trustStore.type
spark.cassandra.connection.ssl.clientAuth.enabled
```

Now I am trying to migrate same application in Kubernetes. I have following questions :

1. Do I need to change above properties in order to connect spark to Cassandra cluster in Kubernetes?
2. Does above properties will work or did I miss something ?
3. Can anyone point to some document or link which can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these properties will continue to work when you run your job on Kubernetes.  The only thing that you need to take into account is that all properties with name ending with `.path` need to point to the actual files with trust & key stores.  On Kubernetes, you need to take care of exposing them as secrets, [mounted as files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod). First you need to create a secret, like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
 spark.truststore:  base64-encoded truststore
kind: Secret
metadata:
 name: spark-truststore
type: Opaque
```

and then in the spec, point to it:

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/some/path"
            name: spark-truststore
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
        - name: spark-truststore
          secret:
            secretName: spark-truststore
```

and point configuration option to given path, like: `/some/path/spark.truststore`